# MSMQ Poison Queue Retry

Tags: wcf, msmq, windows-server-2012

I have setup a self-hosted WCF service setup like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395218%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

For my poison queue processor, I must do the following:

- try to process the message a couple of times
- If retry exhausted, then update a status in the database, and remove the message.

Obviously, using maxRetryCycles and receiveRetryCount is the obvious solution for the first part.  But when the retry cycles are exhausted, I need to delete with a custom action.

What is the best choice of action here, to retry an operation, but log on retry expiration?